# in Emacs wc-mode, how to count characters only in current buffer?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using [wc-mode](https://github.com/bnbeckwith/wc-mode) to count characters in org-mode. However, when I do `org-narrow-to-subtree`, my modeline continues to count all the characters in the entire org file.

How do I direct wc-mode to count only the characters in the currently active buffer, i.e. the current subtree?

Comment: The tag `word-count` might be reaching the wrong target audience, so you may wish to remove that tag just in case one of those folks voted to close your thread.  You may also wish to reword the question a bit so that it doesn't sound so much like a superuser-type question.  It looks like you would need to modify the variable `wc-count-words-function` to put in a condition modifying `rstart` and `rend` so that when the buffer is narrowed it pulls the appropriate two points to restrict the search area.  I've never used that library before; however, the code does not appear to be overly-complex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to customize `wc-modeline-format`.  The following line, for example, will give you the total number of words and total number of characters *in the buffer* (even when narrowed).

```
(setq wc-modeline-format "[Words: %tw, Chars: %tc]")
```